# Can I use a git repo for a subfolder in a mercurial repo?

Tags: git, mercurial

I have a mercurial repo in code.google that includes folders like

```
H
|_ A
|_ B
|_ C
```

The top-level folder H contains sub-folders A, B and C.

Now, I wanted to use Heroku to test the webserver in B, and Heroku only supports git. 
Since the testing is temporal, so I do not want to completely remove B from the mercurial repo. In the meanwhile, manually duplicating B for both hg and git does not seem stable.

Is there any better solution? Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do that - use `git` to version-control your web server in B. But realize that you need to separately commit changes in B for git apart from dealing with `mercurial`.

I believe you can also tweak around with [hg-git](http://hg-git.github.io/) and make it work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Common plan can be (*dirty draft*)

**Using Folder B as git-subrepository in Mercurial repo at permanent basis**

In order to do it (TBT! I can miss some actions)

- Read about [subrepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) in Mercurial (and understand all pros et contas) - also [this guide](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/subrepositories/) from aragost Trifork
- Add hg-git extension to you local Mercurial Installation in oder to work with Git repositories from Mercurial side
- Convert Folder B to Mecurial subrepository (read [manual](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/subrepositories/#converting-folder-into-a-subrepository) again)
- Clone Mercurial's B-repository into additional (external) Git repository
- Replace Mercurial's B-repository with [external](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/subrepositories/#remote-subrepositories) [Git](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository#Git_subrepositories) repository

As expected result you'll be able (I hope) to work with old tree from Mercurial and test independent Git repository in Heroku